# List Analytics sessions data by date

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

can I list Analytics sessions data by date?

2023-07-03 sessions 144

2023-07-05 sessions 132

2023-07-04 sessions 124

2023-07-02 sessions 120

2023-07-01 sessions 84

2023-07-06 sessions 83

listing by sessions in its current form

```
 $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $propertyId,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2023-07-01',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
'dimensions' => [
        new Dimension([
            "name" => "date"
        ])
    ],
    'metrics' => [
      
             new Metric([
            "name" => "sessions"
        ])
   ],
   ]);

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {

echo " ". date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()));
echo " sessions ". $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue();
echo "<br>";
 
}
```

Comment: Your question actually helped me see how to send the date parameter. You are very close to the solution; I think it is almost similar to my code. Have you already found the solution? If not I may try to answer it.